# Azure Databricks MemoryStream support

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, memorystream

I tried some simple `MemoryStream` samples in Azure databricks:

```
val input = MemoryStream[T]
...
input.addData(...)

    input.toDS()
      .writeStream
      .queryName("events")
      .outputMode("update") // or complete
      .format("console") // or memory
      .start()
```

[Spark Structured Streaming MemoryStream + Row + Encoders issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238269/spark-structured-streaming-memorystream-row-encoders-issue)

[Is proper event-time sessionization possible with Spark Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810460/is-proper-event-time-sessionization-possible-with-spark-structured-streaming)

However, when I run them I get

> Job aborted due to stage failure: ...
> java.io.InvalidClassException:
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemoryStream; no valid
> constructor

Is there any work around do this?  Memorystream seems quite useful to do some tests before working with real datasets.   The above code seems to work fine in my local cluster via `Spark-shell` but ideally I don't want to go back and forth between local and databricks clusters to test things.